# Scala Apply Method in companion object

Tags: scala

I have created a companion object for my Scala class with an apply method in it so that I can create an instance of my class without using 'new'.

```
object StanfordTokenizer{
  def apply() = new StanfordTokenizer()
}

class StanfordTokenizer() extends Tokenizer{


  def tokenizeFile(docFile: java.io.File) = new PTBTokenizer(new FileReader(docFile), new CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "").tokenize.map(x => x.word().toLowerCase).toList

  def tokenizeString(str: String) = new PTBTokenizer(new StringReader(str), new CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "").tokenize.map(x => x.word.toLowerCase()).toList

}
```

However when I try to instantiate the StanfordTokenizer class without 'new' e.g. `StandfordTokenizer.tokenizeString(str)`.

I get the error

```
value tokenizeString is not a member of object StanfordTokenizer
```

However, if I explicitly include the apply method like `StandfordTokenizer.apply().tokenizeString(str)` it does work.

I feel like I am missing something fundamental about companion objects.  Can someone shed some light on this for me?
                                 ^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's exactly as the compiler message says. `tokenizeString` is a member of the class `StandfordTokenizer`, but not its companion object. The companion object does not inherit any methods from the class. Therefore, in order to use `tokenizeString`, you need an instance of `StandfordTokenizer` in order to call it.

`StandfordTokenizer.apply` creates an instance of the class `StandfordTokenizer`, which has the method `tokenizeString`. It seems as though the class `StandfordTokenizer` holds no real information, and won't have more than one instance. If that is true, you should probably just make it an object, and you'll be able to acquire the behavior you're looking for.

```
object StanfordTokenizer extends Tokenizer {

    def tokenizeFile(docFile: java.io.File) = ...

    def tokenizeString(str: String) = ...

}
```

This should work as well (as a class):

```
StandfordTokenizer().tokenizeString(str)
```

`StandfordTokenizer` without parenthesis does not call `apply`, it references the object. `StandfordTokenizer()` does call `apply`, and creates a new instance of the class. This is probably the source of your confusion.